# Delete elements from numpy arrays at the same position by using zip() and np.delete()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, zip

I got two 1D arrays of same length (`it` and `l`) and I want to delete the element `y` in `l` for `l` < `ls` and also delete element `x` in `it` at the same position. I tried:

```
for x, y in zip(it, l):
        if y < ls:
            np.delete(l,y)
            np.delete(it,x)
```

But it is not working and there is the Warning:

"DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer array as obj in delete will result in an error in the future"
np.delete(l,y)

"DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer array as obj in delete will result in an error in the future
np.delete(it,x)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have [an example](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).

You have to indicate the index of the element that you want to remove :

```
import numpy as np

it = np.asarray(range(10))
l = np.asarray(range(10))

ls = 4
index = []
for i, y in enumerate(l):
        if y < ls:
            index.append(i)

l = np.delete(l, index)
it = np.delete(it, index)
```

Results :

```
(array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Shorter version :

```
index = np.argwhere(l < ls)
l = np.delete(l, index)
it = np.delete(it, index)
```